# Arduino Serial + Django

Tags: python, django, arduino, serial

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы не разрывать соединение между Arduino и сервером до его закрытия.

Есть ли в django какие-то доступные методы вне web-запросов?

Если просто написать

```py
def index(request):
    serial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
    serial.write(b'start')
```

То будет создаваться новое подключение каждый раз, а это сильно мешает, ведь arduino категорически не надо перезагружать

Заранее благодарен

Comment: Вынести `serial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)` из функции?

Comment: @ГеннадийП я и спрашиваю куда. в какой бы из скриптов я не вынес из другого скрипта я не могу обратиться к этому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для будущих поколений отвечу. Для решения действительно достаточно вынести присвоение serial на уровень выше.

Стоит отметить, что Arduino любит отваливаться от порта, поэтому подключение необходимо иногда проверять:

```py
serial = None

def get_serial(attempts = 5, port = '/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate = 9600):
    global serial
    for i in range(attempts):
        try:
            if serial is None or serial.port is None:
                serial = Serial(port, baudrate, timeout=0)
                sleep(5) # Ожидаем запуска Arduino
            else:
                _ = serial.in_waiting # Когда Arduino отвалится здесь выпадет исключение
            return serial
        except SerialException as e:
            try:
                serial.close()
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            serial = None
        sleep(50)
    return None
```

Ну и старый код можно переписать с использованием новый функции:

```py
def index(request):
    get_serial().write(b'start')
```